# How to configure a MacBook so that it keeps a static IP-address when disconnected?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, network

I have a client/server software that uses IP to communicate. It happens that both client and server is located at the same MacBook, and when I travel I disconnect it from the IP network, making it loose the **static** IP-address obtained by the network card from the IP network. This sets a stop for the IP connection between the client and server.

Both the client and server software is configured to use a specific IP-address and reconfiguration of this address within this software is not possible.
This makes it impossible to change the client/server IP-address configuration to localhost/127.0.0.1, as would be the most obvious solution.

Are there any other way that I can configure my MacBook (Yosemite) network configuration so that it keeps using the static IP-address even if I disconnect it from the IP network?

Comment: Can you change the network settings of the client/server at all? If, for example, you could change it to use a full domain name instead of an IP, you could put an entry in /etc/hosts that redirects all traffic to your.domain.name to 127.0.0.1

Comment: I can understand that the question is a bit unclear on this point. I will rephrase. It is possible to reconfigure **network** settings in Yosemite as I have administrator-access. The problem is that the client and server software will still need to use the static IP-address. I think editing /etc/hosts may be a solution. I will check how I can do that.

Comment: DHCP with fixed address in Network CP?

Comment: If reconfiguring the IP address to a FQDN is not possible, you'd best be using [pfctl](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/pfctl.8.html) to redirect traffic coming from localhost to your static IP back to localhost (it would possibly be best also specifying which port).

Comment: Serverfault had a good answer to the question that uses `ifconfig`: [http://serverfault.com/questions/402744/assigning-multiple-ip-addresses-to-localhost-os-x-10-6](http://serverfault.com/questions/402744/assigning-multiple-ip-addresses-to-localhost-os-x-10-6) I answered the question below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open Applications -> Utilities -> Terminal
2. Enter the following command: `sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 192.168.1.100`
3. Type root password
4. Quit Terminal